# Why left shifting in java changing the sign value

Tags: java, byte-shifting

I am working on java. 
I am wondering why java producing this output.
I am sharing the code here.

```
public class vvn {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        byte [] arr = new byte[4];
        arr[0] = (byte)157;
        arr[1] = 1;
        arr[2] = 0;
        arr[3] = 0;
        System.out.format("read 0x%x 0x%x 0x%x 0x%x \n",arr[3],arr[2],arr[1],arr[0]);
        int v = (arr[0] | (arr[1] << 8) | (arr[2] << 16) | (arr[3] << 24));
        System.out.format("read 0x%x\n",v);

    }

}
```

And I got the output as

```
read 0x0 0x0 0x1 0x9d 
read 0xffffff9d
```

I expected the output should be 0x0000019d

Comment: From java doc
byte: The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive). The byte data type can be useful for saving memory in large arrays, where the memory savings actually matters. They can also be used in place of int where their limits help to clarify your code; the fact that a variable's range is limited can serve as a form of documentation.

Comment: Basically I am reading from a file, 4 times each 1 byte using the datainputstream. Is there any way that I can do this. I give priority to the endianness

Comment: @wn Read an integer and then call `Integer.reverseBytes(x);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are converting from byte (signed 8 bits) to integer (signed 32 bits). The most significant bit (the leftmost one) holds the sign (see [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)).

Your `157` is `10011101` in binary. Since you assign this value to a **signed byte** (java has no unsigned byte), this is in fact a negative number, `-99`.

Now when you convert from byte to int, the value is preserved. In case of negative numbers, this means setting all the bits to the left to preserve the signedness. In your case, `10011101` becomes `11111111 11111111 11111111 10011101`.

Anyway, working with unsigned bytes in java is a nightmare. Basically, you need to mask everything with 0xff (to cut off the 'ones to the left') like this:

```
int v = ((arr[0] & 0xff) |
    ((arr[1] & 0xff) << 8) |
    ((arr[2] & 0xff) << 16) |
    ((arr[3] & 0xff) << 24));
```

Beautiful, isn't it?

**Update 1:** Also, you may be interested in Guava's [UnsignedBytes](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedBytes.html)...

**Update 2:** Java 8 Byte has toUnsignedInt() and toUnsignedLong() methods. Your calculation thus becomes:

```
int v = (Byte.toUnsignedInt(arr[0]) |
    (Byte.toUnsignedInt(arr[1]) << 8) |
    (Byte.toUnsignedInt(arr[2]) << 16) |
    (Byte.toUnsignedInt(arr[3]) << 24));
```

Answer (score 1):

Look. 
Your expression *(arr[1] << 8) | (arr[2] << 16) | (arr[3] << 24)* equals to Ox100.
So, you need extra Ox9d, which is in decimal is 157. Unfortunatly, byte diapasone is [-128; 127]. So, it is impossible to get 157 from byte. And your a[0] is equal to `-99`.

Answer (score 0):

Because the left most digit is reserved for sign, when you shift left the sign changes when you commit an overflow.

Comment: I doubt that "when you shift left the sign changes" is true.

Comment: When we shift left the sign dont change I think.

Comment: Modified my answer fore the completness.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, The type `byte` is a signed value from -128 to 127. This means that `(byte)157` result in an overflow and is actually equal to `-99`. When you output the hexadecimal value of the byte is not apparerent, because the binary representation of `-99` (signed) and `157` (unsigned) is equal (and the format conversion `%x` interprets the value as an unsigned value).

However, as soon as you use it in an expression, the `byte` value is promoted to an `int`. And the hexadecimal representation of -99 as an int is `0xffffff9d`. You can see this by adding the following line to your program:

```
System.out.format("0x%x \n", (int)arr[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that bitwise operations in java are performed on `int`s
So when you use

```
arr[0] | ...
```

`arr[0]` is converted to `int`. So instead of the expected `0x9d`, you get `0xffffff9d`
So the solve the issue you need to `&` the `0xff` mask, e.g.

```
int v = ((arr[0] & 0xff) | ((arr[1] & 0xff) << 8) | ...;
```